# Convert pdf to text with colors

Tags: go, pdf

I am trying to convert a pdf to text, and als extract the color information of the text.

I am trying to do this in golang, but using a command line tool I call from golang is absolutely acceptable.

I found `pdftotext` from `poppler-utils`, and its almost perfect. Only, it does not give me the color information.

I tried github.com/ledongthuc/pdf, which also does not give me color information.

Is there some other tool? Am I missing a way to do this with pdftotext?

Comment: Do you want to do PDF to Text or Text to PDF? Question title and content don't match.

Comment: @VikramKumar wow, I am sorry. Thanks for pointing that out. I want pdf to text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a C++ library called `poppler` (https://poppler.freedesktop.org), which allows extracting text from PDF Files including color.

There a go bindings here: https://github.com/cheggaaa/go-poppler